# Getting 403 when updating client_LocationBasedDefaults.html in Forms folder in Document Library with Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, 403, document-upload

I'm attempting to use REST to update the client_LocationBasedDefaults.html file in my SharePoint Online's document library's Forms folder using the `/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/myLibrary/Forms')/Files/add(url='client_LocationBasedDefaults.html', overwrite=true)` Endpoint, but I keep getting a 403 error. 
I've checked my form digest, X-RequestDigest, and it's correct.

I can upload to any other folder using my method, but when I try to upload to my Document Library's "/Forms" folder, I get this error. Is there some hidden setting I need to flip to enable write access to Forms via REST?

Thanks!

EDIT: Code snippet of method

`public void uploadFile(){
    String documentLibraryPath = 'sites/Shared%20Documents';
    String formDigestValue = getFormDigestValue();
    Http httpInstanceUpload = new Http();
    HttpRequest reqUpload = new HttpRequest();
    reqUpload.setEndpoint('callout:Sharepoint_Connection/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'' +'/'+ documentLibraryPath + '/Forms' + '\')/Files/add(url=\'client_LocationBasedDefaults.html\',overwrite=true)');
    reqUpload.setMethod('POST');
    reqUpload.setHeader('X-RequestDigest', formDigestValue);
    reqUpload.setBody('<MetadataDefaults><a href="/sites/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder/"><DefaultValue FieldName="TestDefaultValue">Hi</DefaultValue></a></MetadataDefaults>');
    HttpResponse uploadResponse = httpInstanceUpload.send(reqUpload);
}`

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet of your upload function?

Comment: I edited the post above with the code snippet.